# Thermodynamic temperature scale

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

I was wondering why is it that I can replace heat going into a carnot engine with the temperature of the "hot place" and vice versa, i.e , why can the temperatures of the places replace the heat going in and out of the engine

Answer (score 4):

Because the transported thermal energy, that you call "heat", is really transported *entropy* $S$ at some temperature $T$, so that the thermal energy transported is $TS$. Since in a reversible process the entropy is conserved, if the engine absorbs entropy $\Delta S$ at the higher temperature, $T_1$, then to finish its cycle returning to its starting state it must somewhere dump the *same* amount of entropy at a lower temperature, say, $T_2$. The differences of the two energies, $T_1\Delta S$ and $T_2\Delta S$, is the work $\Delta W$ done by the engine, $$\Delta W =T_1\Delta S-T_2\Delta S=(T_1-T_2)\Delta S$$ as the entropy falls through a temperature gradient, just as a heavy mass $\delta m$ does work $(\phi_1-\phi_2)\delta m$ as it drops through a gravitational gradient $\phi_1-\phi_2$.
Note how the amount of entropy falls out when the efficiency is calculated relative to the absorbed thermal energy, "heat", $\delta Q_1=T_1 \Delta S$:

$$\eta = \frac{\Delta W}{\delta Q_1} =\frac{T_1\Delta S-T_2\Delta S}{T_1 \Delta S}=\frac{T_1-T_2}{T_1 },$$
and only the two extreme temperatures matter at which heat absorption and rejection take place.